# Expressing double integrals in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, special-functions, polar-coordinates

I have the double integrals

$\int_{x}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-\Lambda^a(x^a+y^a)}dxdy$

where $a$ and $\Lambda$ are real positive constants.

I would like to express it in polar coordinates. What are my $r$ and $\theta$?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the limits of integration in this order?

Answer (score 5):

The given integral equals
$$\frac{1}{\Lambda^2}\iint_{0\leq x \leq y}\exp\left[-(x^a+y^a)\right]\,dx\,dy =\frac{4}{a^2\Lambda^2}\int_{0\leq u\leq v} (uv)^{2/a-1}e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\,du\,dv$$
or
$$ \frac{4}{a^2\Lambda^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\rho(\rho^2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^{2/a-1} e^{-\rho^2}\,d\theta\,d\rho $$
or
$$ \frac{2}{a^2\Lambda^2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{a}\right)\,2^{-2/a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin t\right)^{2/a-1}\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{2^{-2/a} \sqrt{\pi }\; \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{a}\right)\, \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}{a^2 \Lambda^2\, \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)}} $$
for any $a>0$.

Comment: Please, can you clarify why  your starting integral is the same as the integral in OP? Tanks!

Comment: I just used trivial substitutions, polar coordinates and ultimately the integral definitions of the $\Gamma$ and Beta functions.

Comment: all too easy (+1)

Comment: What I 'don't understand is the $1/\Lambda^2$ factor.

Comment: @EmilioNovati: The very first step is to replace $x$ with $\frac{x}{\Lambda}$ and similarly $y$ with $\frac{y}{\Lambda}$.

Comment: For instance, in the single variable case $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(\Lambda x)\,dx = \frac{1}{\Lambda}\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Yes (stupid question), thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. I understand that you used the substitution $\rho=x^2+y^2$, $x=r cos(\phi)$ and $y=r sin(\phi)$, but can you please show me how you got the new integral limits?

Comment: @kazekage: there is an obvious parametrization of the region $0\leq x\leq y$ in polar coordinates, given by $\rho\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\theta\in\left[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: how would the results change if the integral limit changes from x->infinity to B->infinity?

Comment: @kazekage: you already have a comment of mine about such integral. In that case you get the product between a Gamma and an incomplete Gamma by Fubini's theorem.